# How do you install an SSL certificate on IIS 6 and 7?

Tags: .net, iis-7, iis-6, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

Is there a tool or programmatic way to install an SSL certificate to the default website in IIS 6 and 7?  Ideally I am looking for something that can be done via unmanaged code or .NET managed code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/bf6b6472-f58e-4271-9297-284357f69023.mspx?mfr=true

Something like:
set ssl = CreateObject("IIS.CertObj")

ssl.InstanceName = "0.0.0.0:443"

ssl.Import pfxfile, pfxfilepassword, true, true